# How to load a model in CodeIgniter HMVC into an autoload?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

Hello guys just need a little help here. I am trying to study and create a CRUD in CodeIgniter with HMVC approach but I have a difficulty in loading the model. Here's my structure:

CRUD

```
   - application
     - config
        - autoload.php
     - modules_code
        - address
          - controllers
          - models
          - views
        - locations
          - controllers
            - locations.php
          - models
            - locations_model.php
          - views
        - member
          - controllers
            - member.php
          - models
          - views
   - css
   - js
   - third_party
```

My problem is I can't autoload the model in autoload.php which is under config folder
Here's the autoload code:

```
$autoload['model'] = array('locations_model');
```

Inside my locations_model.php:

```
<?php

    class locations_model extends CI_Model{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function getAllCountries(){

            $sql = "SELECT code,country FROM cscart_country_descriptions";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);

            return json_encode($result->result_array());

        }

    }

?>
```

In my controller I have this:

```
<?php

    class Member extends MX_Controller{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index(){

            $data['title'] = "Welcome to HHAlliance Member Point!";
            $data['project_title'] = "HH-Alliance - Login Page";

            $this->load->view('common/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('index',$data);
            $this->load->view('common/footer',$data);

        }

        public function authUser(){





        }

        public function register(){

            $data['title'] = "HHAlliance - User Account Registration";
            $data['project_title'] = "HH-Alliance Member Registration";
            $data['countries'] = $this->locations_model->getAllCountries();

            $this->load->view('common/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('user_register');
            $this->load->view('common/footer',$data);

        }


    }

?>
```

Here's my error:

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to locate the model you have specified: locations_model
```

Comment: have you tried $autoload['model'] = array('modules_code/locations_model');

but what I usually do is $this->load->model('Model_name');

Comment: I already tried that but it is not working. What I did now is to access it every controller. In the construct function I have a code like this:

$this->load->model('modulename/modelname');

Comment: got no idea :( it's logically works that way.

Comment: Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/models.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change your model class name to

```
class Locations_model extends CI_Model{
   ....
}
```

Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase.

then,

```
$autoload['models'] = array('locations_model');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of your model class from locations_model to Locations_model.
And use $this->load->model('module_name'); only in the controller or method that need this model.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly change the name of your model classs name locations_model to Locations_model.
And use codiegnieter method for loading model in controller.

```
$this->load->model('model_name','model_alias_name');


<?php

    class Member extends MX_Controller{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('locations_model','locations');

        }

        public function index(){

            $data['title'] = "Welcome to HHAlliance Member Point!";
            $data['project_title'] = "HH-Alliance - Login Page";

            $this->load->view('common/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('index',$data);
            $this->load->view('common/footer',$data);

        }

        public function authUser(){





        }

        public function register(){

            $data['title'] = "HHAlliance - User Account Registration";
            $data['project_title'] = "HH-Alliance Member Registration";
            $data['countries'] = $this->locations->getAllCountries();

            $this->load->view('common/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('user_register');
            $this->load->view('common/footer',$data);

        }


    }

?>
```